# Why my facebook log in code not ask user for permission?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why my facebook log in code not ask user for permission ?

Normally facebook lo ing on other website. when user log in with facebook on first time. It's will show ask permission box. But my facebook login code not show ask permission box. (still log in success)

How can i do for show ask permission box

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
session_start();
ob_start();
define('APP_ID', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // Your Facebook Application ID goes in here
define('APP_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // Your Facebook Application Secret goes in here
define('LOGIN_PAGE_URL', 'https://www.example.com/'); // The URL to your login page ending with a slash goes in here. Example: https://www.vasplus.info/demos/login_with_fb/
include 'vpb_fb/facebook.php';
//Facebook Application Details
$facebook_application_info = new Facebook(array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET));
//Get Facebook user id      
$vpb_get_user = $facebook_application_info->getUser();
/**************************************************************************************************
* This script is brought to you by Vasplus Programming Blog by whom all copyrights are reserved.
* Website: www.vasplus.info
* Email: vasplusblog@gmail.com or info@vasplus.info
* Do not remove this information from the top of this page please.
***************************************************************************************************/

//Be sure that the user id is not an empty field before you can proceed
if ($vpb_get_user && !empty($vpb_get_user)) 
{
    try { $vpb_fetch_data = $facebook_application_info->api('/me'); }  // This user is authenticated therefore, proceed
    catch (FacebookApiException $ex) 
    {
        error_log($ex);
        $vpb_get_user = null;
    }

    //Be sure user data from Facebook is not empty
    if (!empty( $vpb_fetch_data )) 
    {
        $uid = $vpb_fetch_data['id'];
        $first_name = $vpb_fetch_data['first_name'];
        $last_name = $vpb_fetch_data['last_name'];
        $full_name = $vpb_fetch_data['name'];
        $user_name = $vpb_fetch_data['username'];
        $email = $vpb_fetch_data['email'];
        $gender = $vpb_fetch_data['gender'];
        $birthday = $vpb_fetch_data['birthday'];
        $location = $vpb_fetch_data['location'];
        $bio = $vpb_fetch_data['bio'];

        $vpb_fb_logout = array('next' => LOGIN_PAGE_URL.'logout.php'); 
        $logout_url = $facebook_application_info->getLogoutUrl($vpb_fb_logout);
        $_SESSION['complete_logout'] = $logout_url;

        // Be sure that the most important user info are in place then proceed
        if(!empty($uid))
        {
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $username_user; 
            $_SESSION['admin'] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            // There was an error therefore, take the user back to the login page
            header('location: index.php?facebook_error=1'); // If the user denies the application access to his or her account
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // There was an error therefore, take the user back to the login page
        header('location: index.php?facebook_error=2'); // If something go wrong
    }
} 
else 
{
    // There was an error therefore, take the user to login via Facebook again with permission info
    $vpb_login_url = $facebook_application_info->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email, user_birthday, user_location, user_photos', 'redirect_uri' => LOGIN_PAGE_URL.'facebook_redirect_to_index.php'));

    header("location: " . $vpb_login_url);
}
?>
```